# Why is Sumproduct formula showing #Value error?

Tags: arrays, excel-formula, valueerror

I receive a #value error while using the sumproduct formulas.
The main idea behind this document is to track the actuals on a daily basis using the following conditions:

- If the date is equal to the one specified in cell E2
- If the team name found in ranges e18:e46 or e50:e52 are the same as listed in the range C4:C8
- Sum the values found for those specific columns

Added the document for reference [Excel File](https://www.mediafire.com/file/ztlen237wluzka9/test.xlsx/file)

I can't figure out what's wrong. Also to be specified that if i manually fill up random values in the table, the formula works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuase you have empty values in your return matrix. So you are multiplying with "0".

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(E50:E52=C5)*(G17:AH17=E2),(G50:AH52))
```